# How can I use the arrow keys in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, google-suggest

I'm trying to mimic the Google suggestions list with this:

```
function el(tid) {
    return document.getElementById(tid);
}

function addScript(u) {
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
        sc2 = document.createElement('script');
    sc2.src = u;
    head.appendChild(sc2);
    setTimeout(function () {
        head.removeChild(sc2);
        sc2 = null;
    }, 600);
} //end addScript()

function suggest(data) {
    var sel = el("test");
    sel.innerHTML = '';
    for (x = 0; x < data[1].length; x++) {
        sel.innerHTML += '<li class="uli" >' + data[1][x][0] + '</li>';
    }
}


el("inp").onkeyup = function () {
    addScript("http://www.google.nl/complete/search?callback=suggest&q=" + this.value);
};
```

The problem is that I want to be able to come down in the suggestions list using the arrow keys, and secondary I want to show the 'current' suggestion value inside the input field. So I tried something like this using Jquery:

```
$("#inp").live("keydown", function (e) {


    var curr = $('#test').find('.current');
    if (e.keyCode == 40) {
        if (curr.length) {
            $(curr).attr('class', 'uli');
            curr = $(curr).next();
        }
        if (curr.length) {
            curr.attr('class', 'uli current');
        } else {
            $('#center li:first-child').attr('class', 'uli current');

        }
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 38) {
        if (curr.length) {
            $(curr).attr('class', 'uli');
            curr = $(curr).prev();
        }
        if (curr.length) {
            curr.attr('class', 'uli current');
        } else {
            $('#center li:last-child').attr('class', 'uli current');
        }
    }







    $("#inp").live("keydown", function (e) {
        var search_terms = $('li.current').text();

        if (e.keyCode == 40) {
            $('#inp').val(search_terms);
        }
        if (e.keyCode == 38) {
            $('#inp').val(search_terms);

        }
```

It doesn't work because (I think..) the 'current' suggestion is immediately being requested by the previous code. 
I have put everything over here:  [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/uxepay/edit#javascript,html,live)

Comment: So I got it to work using onkeypress like this: `el("inp").onkeypress=function(){
  addScript("http://www.google.nl/complete/search?callback=suggest&q="+this.value);
}` But now it doesn't respond on the very first key press but from the second one on. Ho can I solve this?

Comment: Oh no I just discovered the backspace doesn't work with keypress, so never mind...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why recreate the wheel?

[jQuery UI Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/)

Or look at other [plugins](http://plugins.jquery.com/)

The problem with your code is you need to cancel out the arrow keypresses when you call to get the values.

```
el("inp").onkeyup = function () {
    //if not the arrow keys, fetch the list
    if( ... ){
        addScript("http://www.google.nl/complete/search?callback=suggest&q=" + this.value);
    }
}
```

Also what is with `el("inp")` when you are using jQuery? I expected to see `$("foo").keyup( function(){} );`

Comment: I think I would have to use the ui library, which I want to avoid because its so big. But thank's for the reference. I see there is an example of how to use it with an xml file, that should do the trick. But than again I dont have the xml on my server, so that could be a problem...Any way if my 'simple' (small code) approach doesn't work I will definitely look in to it and see if it can solve my problem (and than of course except your answer)

Comment: I know, and I have been looking for a way to cancel out the arrow keys for a while now but there is no reference on the internet what so ever...So I really don't know how to do that.

Comment: I once wrote the code in Jquery but there was no change in behavior, the code did the same thing, it just looked different

Comment: cancel out the arrows? You just say if it is not an arrow, than call the script. lol. Opposite of what you do to move the selection with the arrows. ;)

Comment: How do you say "if not an arrow"? Stating IF is much easier than stating IF NOT ;)

Comment: JavaScript 101 using `!` for not. `if(e.keyCode !== 38 && e.keyCode !== 40){`

Comment: I have excepted your answer because it WORKS:) Yes I'm a newbie but I want to finish my first project before learning javascript. So far I managed using Jquery. Thank you very much:)